# No store on url

Tags: virtocommerce

i am new in virtocommerce i am following the steps

http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Source+Code+Getting+Started

In the last step **Start Storefront** i can not get any store and the url is shown : 
***http://localhost:46761/common/nostore***

[image]

How i can run the application.

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue that happens under certain circumstances. Re-download latest release (source code) as it was fixed recently.

Answer (score 0):

The "Let's start!" should open the VirtoCommerce Manager, but the default link URL is not correct in your case.

Open the Manager site, login and choose "Download sample data" initially. Storefront should display sample stores after data import is complete.